# Automate Azure Batch pool quota increase

Tags: azure, azure-batch-account

Once an azure batch account is create you'll probably have to go to Batch quota and request increase in pools limits:

[image]

Is there a way to automate this so I don't have to log in to Azure Portal? I tried using az cli to query requests

```
az quota request status list --scope "/subscriptions/$subid/resourceGroups/$rg/providers/Microsoft.Batch/batchAccounts/$batchaccount"
```

but I get following error:

[image]

There's also this command to check current limits but it depends on shared key to communicate with AzBatch, which in UserSubscription mode is not possible, since AAD auth is required.